# How to disable right click only on desktop and icons in XFCE4?

Tags: debian, xfce, mouse, kiosk

I am building a kiosk machine with Debian 9.8 and XFCE4.

Everything is done except disabling right click in Desktop.

Tried `xmodmap -e 'pointer = 1 2 0 4 5 6 7 8 9'`;
however, it disabled right click every where, i.e., in application too.

I need to 
disable the right click on desktop & icons.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the right click menu in xfdesktop you'll need to compile it with ./configure --disable-desktop-menu

also you can try this.
If you're using Xfce 4.10, you may try the following:

In Settings > Desktop > Menus uncheck Show applications on right click and perhaps uncheck Show window list on middle click.

If in addition you go to Settings > Desktop > Icons and select type: None or Minimized, then this should pretty much disable all interaction with the desktop.

Comment: You mean only compile only xfdesktop xfdesktop? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: sorry i didn't get what you said properly. yes compile xfdesktop again. you don't need other xfce packages like xfce4-session.

Comment: let me know if my answer was helpful. and don't forget to accept my answer as correct answer if it works.